# Login from outer page

Tags: jsf, authentication, primefaces

I have two websites. I use JSF 2.0 with Primefaces..
The first website (www.mysiteone.com) has a login page (username + password)..
I have to login to the first website (www.mysiteone.com) from the second website (www.mysitetwo.com)..
How can I do that?

Comment: There are countless ways to do such a thing. Did you do any research?

Comment: yes i do... but nothing clear and simple to do..